# Rails 3.1 Show user name in images controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a web app which uses Devise for authentication. It is a site which allows the user to upload images so the url would be `/images/2`. There is a separate image controller.

How would I go about showing the Users name on that image? I have put `= user.name` to show the user name, this is HAML by the way. I have also tried `= @user.name`

`= user.name` shows `undefined local variable or method user for #<#<Class:0x007f8f9c28d2e0>:0x007f8f9c287f70>`

`= @user.name` shows `undefined method name for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an association between the image and the user that posted the image? Like this:

```
# image.rb
belongs_to :user

# user.rb
has_many :images
```

In that case you do not have to set the @user variable in your controller. You can access the owning user directly by using `@image.user` in your view. To post the username you can chain it like this: `@image.user.name`, even better would be to modify the to_s method of your user as shown below. This method gets called automatically if you try to display your object, so you could just display the name using `@image.user` then.

```
# user.rb
def to_s
  self.name
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah using `@image.user.name` shows the users name. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `@user.name` fails because you are not setting the `@user` variable to the correct value while your are in your image controller.

Try also whether `current_user` returns you an instance. In other words, instead of `= @user.name` try `= current_user.name`.

I cannot give you more info. I have never worked with `Devise` in the past.

Comment: Yep, `= current_user.name` works. However, I want it to show the users name who posted that image.